# timeout value when executing method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to modify a table in my database but when it comes to the choice of running about thirty seconds left hooked and then presents timeout error. I am using Sql server 2012 and C #.

Here the code and structure of the table.

Table Estudiante

```
IdEstudiante            Int,
Est_PrimerNombre        varchar(15),
Est_SegundoNombre       varchar(15),
Est_PrimerApellido      varchar(15),
Est_SegundoApellido     varchar(15),
Est_FechaNacimiento     datetime,
Est_Edad                Int,
IdTutor                 Int,
IdCurso                 Int,
Est_CuotaMensual        numeric(18,2),
IdAnioEscolar           Int,
Est_NumeroSegSocial     varchar(20),
Est_NumeroAfiliado      varchar(20),
Est_CompaniaAseguradora varchar(50),
Est_Estado              Int
```

And the code:

```
public void EditEstudiante()
{
    SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnxString"].ToString());

    cnx.Close();

    query = @"UPDATE Estudiante SET 
                Est_PrimerNombre = @Est_PrimerNombre,
                Est_SegundoNombre = @Est_SegundoNombre,
                Est_PrimerApellido = @Est_PrimerApellido,
                Est_SegundoApellido = @Est_SegundoApellido,
                Est_FechaNacimiento = @Est_FechaNacimiento,
                Est_Edad = @Est_Edad,
                IdTutor = @IdTutor,
                IdCurso = @IdCurso,
                Est_CuotaMensual = @Est_CuotaMensual, 
                IdAnioEscolar = @IdAnioEscolar,
                Est_NumeroSegSocial = @Est_NumeroSegSocial,
                Est_NumeroAfiliado = @Est_NumeroAfiliado, 
                Est_CompaniaAseguradora = @Est_CompaniaAseguradora,
                Est_Estado = @Est_Estado                        
             WHERE IdEstudiante = @IdEstudiante";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_PrimerNombre", edtPNombre.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_SegundoNombre", edtSNombre.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_PrimerApellido", edtPApellido.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_SegundoApellido", edtSApellido.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_FechaNacimiento", Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFechaNac.Value));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_Edad", Convert.ToInt32(edtEdad.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTutor", Convert.ToInt32(edtTutor.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCurso", Convert.ToInt32(cbCurso.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_CuotaMensual", edtCuota.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdAnioEscolar", Convert.ToInt32(cbAnioEscolar.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_NumeroSegSocial", edtNumeroSeguroSocial.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_NumeroAfiliado", edtNumeroAfiliado.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_CompaniaAseguradora", edtCompaniaSeguro.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_Estado", Convert.ToInt32(cbEstado.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdEstudiante", Convert.ToInt32(IdTemp));

    cnx.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnx.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Estudiante Modificado");
}
```

Comment: Set cmd.CommandTimeout to something > 30.

Comment: That should never take more than 30 seconds. I can only imagine the nightmare of triggers and table locks that would ever cause that.

Comment: I don't know if it would solve your problem, but your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: @TyCobb, the table/row could be locked so it is not so impossible

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Agreed, but then increasing the timeout is basically a moot bandage.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of timeout of command is 30 secs, so you can increase thus value:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = `number of seconds`;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Giorgi has already provided the correct answer of how to increase the timeout from the SqlCommand.

However, I fear you have a much bigger issue on your hands from what I am seeing. Doing a single row update should not timeout after 30 seconds. If you are getting timeouts due to table or row locks, then I would be researching what it is that is causing the lock and how to improve it. Applications will fail and customers/users will be very mad when they entered in information and are unable to save the data. Increasing the timeout is just a bandage. It doesn't actually solve the problem. You may set it to 60 seconds. It works for a month and then you find you need to set it to 90, then 120, and so on. See the problem?

An even bigger issue is if you are not getting locks, but that update statement is actually taking longer than 30 seconds to execute. Something is seriously wrong with that table, server, etc. If there are triggers on that table for when updates occur, I would look into how to increase the performance of them. Your example is just updating a single row, but what happens when you need to add a new column and then run an update script against all the rows?